# Is it possible to store encrypted passwords in a separate file for Apache Tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat

I am a new user for apache-tomcat-7.0.52. I need to develop some authentication module for my application and need to understand if it is possible to store  users encrypted passwords in a separate file and if so how should I do that. My authentication module probably should contain password file compatible with  apache-tomcat-7.0.52, so first I need to find out the format of that file.

Thank you,
-Grigor